# Conditions on a set in $\mathbf{R}^3$ such that a curve can passes through its boundary only finitely many times

Tags: algebraic-topology, intuition

Let $S$ be a connected subset of $\mathbf{R}^3$. I would like to know if there is any condition on $S$ under which any straight line $p: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^3$, where $p(0) \in S$ and $p(1) \notin S$, passes through the boundary of $S$ only *finitely many times*.

Here *passing through* may be defined as follows.

The curve $p$ is said to enter the boundary $\partial S$ from $A$ at time $t$ if $p(t) \in \partial S$ and there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $p(t - \delta) \in A$ for all $0 < \delta < \varepsilon$.

The curve $p$ is said to leave the boundary $\partial S$ to $A$ at time $t$ if $p(t) \in \partial S$ and there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $p(t + \delta) \in A$ for all $0 < \delta < \varepsilon$.

The curve $p$ *passes through* $\partial S$ if one of the following happens:

- $p$ enters $\partial S$ from ext($S$) at time $t_0$ and leaves $\partial S$ to int($S$) at time $t_1$ where $p(t) \in \partial S, \forall t \in [t_0, t_1]$.
- $p$ enters $\partial S$ from int($S$) at time $t_0$ and leaves $\partial S$ to ext($S$) at time $t_1$ where $p(t) \in \partial S, \forall t \in [t_0, t_1]$.

Note that $t_0$ may be equal to $t_1$.

I tried to think of it first in two dimensional. If I have a set $S$ whose boundary has some portion containing infinite *wiggles* (I think of if as something similar to the topologist's sine curve), there might be a case where a curve $p$, starting inside $S$ and ending outside, passes through the boundary infinitely many times.

[image: $p$ passes through the boundary of $S$ infinitely many times]

What conditions would prevent this situations from happening (in general)? I guess there may be some conditions on some kind of regularity of the boundary of the set $S$. Can anyone point me to some related keywords?

EDIT(1): Added the notion of *passing through*.

EDIT(2): Added an assumption on $p$.

EDIT(3): Restricted $p$ to be a straight line

EDIT(4): I think differentiability of the boundary curve (in two dimensional case, for example) might be related here. For example, from the figure above, I generated the boundary curve by attaching a segment of curve $y = x\sin(1/x)$, from $x = 0$ to some positive number, to some *smooth* curves. This boundary curve does not have continuous first derivative. I suspect that other boundaries with these kinds of *infinite wiggles* (still do know how to address it properly, though) would not have continuous derivative as well. Maybe if the boundary curve is $C^1-$ or $C^2-$continuous (and the path $p$ is a straight line), $p$ will then pass through the boundary of $S$ only finitely many times? Is there any related result? And can this idea be generalized to the three dimensional case as well?

Comment: You might need to define 'pass through'.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I added the notion of *passing through* the boundary into the post. I wonder if there is a formal way to define so. What I added is only what I think of when I say the curve is passing through the boundary.

Comment: I think you may need to restrict the family of curves you're considering, say, to have only finitely many segments --- have you tried constructing a piecewise-linear curve of finite length that has pathological behavior, a la the boundary of $S$ in your picture?

Comment: I see. I just realized that I forgot to mention that I assume that $p$ does not have that pathological behavior. So the only thing that could cause the problem would be the boundary of $S$.

Comment: Ah okay. (Just to nitpick, part of the game is writing down what "pathological behavior, such as infinite wiggles" means. :)

Comment: Would $S$ consisting of a single element satisfy you? How about the graph of a real-analytic function $R^2\to R$?

Comment: I would prefer $S$ being more general than that. Does $\partial S$ being a real-analytic function imply that the boundary does not have such pathological behavior? I will look into that. I don't know how to describe the idea of *pathological behaviors* mathematically. If real-analyticity does imply so, can it be generalized to $3$D case as well?

Comment: @PetchPuttichai: I have no idea what "pathological" means for you; it has to be your job to figure this out in order to have a well defined question. Is the graph of the function $(x,y)\mapsto e^x$ pathological?

Comment: Hm. Actually, that is the one of the questions I am asking here --- the *related keywords*. How about I assume $p$ is just a straight line?